# probability for uncountable set

Tags: probability

I have read that for an uncountable set, a "typical" probability is p({ω}) = 0 for all ω. This can't be possible for a countable set, since P(Ω) = 1 wouldn't be satisfied. Why is it possible for an uncountable set and why is it "typical" for an uncountable set?

Comment: It is "typical" in the sense that it cannot happen if the set is *not* uncountable, as you pointed out in your question.

Comment: In my book there are two problems (for the reader). The first one being "Suppose Ω is a countable or finite set. Is it possible that p({ω}) = 0 for all ω that belongs to Ω? Why or why not?" The second then says: "Suppose Ω is a uncountable set. It is possible that p({ω}) = 0 for all ω that belongs to Ω? Why or why not?" 

Is it really sufficient to answer the why-question by saying it is possible in the case of an uncountable set because it is not possible in the case of a countable or finite set?

Comment: No, that is not sufficient. The second question can only be answered by providing an example of a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ where $\Omega$ is uncountable, $\{\omega\}\in\mathcal A$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ and $P(\{\omega\})=0$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. Can you do that? My first comment was only focused on the word "typical".

Comment: Nope, I can't do that. But today I read something about the probability really being the length of something, which means P({ω}) = 0 for all ω because ω is a point which is of course of length 0. And in such a case, the set must be uncountable since every point in a certain interval can't be countable. Does that have something to do with it all? (I just started reading about probability, hence the stupid questions.)

Comment: E.g. on interval like $[0,1]$ there is the so-called [uniform continuous distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). As you describe the probability of a subinterval is nothing else there but the length of that interval. Also $P(\{t\})=0$ for each $t\in[0,1]$. So you are clearly on the right track with it. I wish you the best with your study on probability, and do not hesitate to keep asking questions. They are not considered to be stupid as long as they are justified by a lack of knowledge and/or understanding.